# Nesting listof* to achieve this appendices list?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'd like to create a list of appendices like the one shown here:

[image]

I know I can print the different lists with the listof* macros, but I have not the slightes clue how I would add the stand-alone entries for the glossary and the statement of authorship to the list.

Basically, what I'm trying to achive is to create a new list using

```
\newlistof{appendices}{apx}{\TitleOfAppendicesList}
```

and use calls like

```
\addcontentsfromlist{apx}{\listoffigures}
\addcontentsfromlist{apx}{\listoftables}
\addcontentsfromlist{apx}{\lstlistoflistings}
\addcontentsline{apx}{chapter}{\TitleOfGlossary}
\addcontentsline{apx}{chapter}{\TitleOfStatementOfAuthorship}
```

My approach so far can be seen [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/dvtkjjwgdktb).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numberedsection]{glossaries}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup%
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
  \endgroup}
  \renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup%
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
  \endgroup}
  \renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\begingroup%
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
  \endgroup}
}

\newglossaryentry{Application Programming Interface (API)}{
  name=Application Programming Interface (API),
  description={is an interface exposed by some piece of software so that other software can use this particular piece of software.}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % adds to itself (first entry called "Contents") - not wanted

\clearpage
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
Some figure content.
\caption{Figure description.}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline \\
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\ \hline
some & tabular & data \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table description.}
\label{tables:table1}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{List of appendices}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of source code listings}
\providecommand\StatementOfAuthorshipTitle{Statement of authorship}

\chapter*{\appendixtocname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixtocname}
\listoffigures % adds to the table of content - not wanted
\listoftables % same
\lstlistoflistings % same
% how to add glossary & other artefacts here?

% actual contents follow the list of appendices
% each content group shall get its own heading, followed by their contents
% those headings must not appear in the table of contents, but have to appear in the list of appendices

\clearpage
\chapter*{\lstlistlistingname}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,caption={The Hello-World-Example, in C++},captionpos=b,frame=single]
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\clearpage
\chapter*{\StatementOfAuthorshipTitle}
inclusion of the statement document (PDF file)
%\includepdf[pages=-]{artefacts/statement.pdf}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Apparently you're using the `tocloft` package . Please add to your post what you have done so far, not just a few lines of code. Are the figures/tables etc just the one from other appendices or from the whole document?

Answer (score 4):

Using `tocbibind` and `appendix` and the packages for `glossaries`, `listings` this not really a problem.

Just redefine the relevant `\listof...` commands and use `\tocsection` command in conjunction with the `\tocfile{\listofsomethingname}{ext}`.

For `glossaries`, the `numberedsection` package option is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage[numberedsection]{glossaries}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup%
  \tocsection
  \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}

\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup%
  \tocsection
  \tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
\endgroup}


\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\begingroup%
  \tocsection
  \tocfile{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
\endgroup}

}


\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={A foobar}
}

\makeglossaries


\setglossarysection{section}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\section{My first section}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[5]
\begin{table}
\caption{Dummy table}
\end{table}


\section{Another section}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption={The Hello-World-Example}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}

\clearpage
\begin{appendices}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\lstlistoflistings

\printglossaries
\end{appendices}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is getting close to it. I'm using the KOMA script class `scrreprt` for my document so I get page breaks after every use of \listof*. Also, no content shall be printed inside the list of appendices, but in the pages after the list. The TOC is also getting filled. And how would I go about listing other artefacts like the statement of authorship? I've updated my question to provide my current approach.

Comment: @Advanium: You added no working code, actually, only a few lines. And about KOMA, well, I find that classes weird

Comment: I actually provided a link at the bottom of the post. I'm sorry I didn't state that clearly. I've updated the post to also provide the latest code.

Comment: `nottoc` as an option to `tocbibind` cures the `ToC` appearance of the `ToC` itself. And `tocloft` etc. do not really go well with KOMA. I fear, I can't help here (I've dropped KOMA support about two years ago)